# ReactJS: Component is not rendering in Nested Routing

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I am using `"react-scripts": "4.0.2"` and all my components are React Hooks. My logic involves nested routing but the end result is not rendered.

**Body.js:**

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/form" exact component={Forms}></Route>
    <Route path="/" exact component={ShopCards}></Route>
</Switch>
```

**Forms.js:**

```
const expandFormHandler = (pid) => {
console.log("PID:" + pid);           //It is printing correcly
props.history.push({ pathname: "/form/" + pid });  //URL is also changing accordingly
}

return (
<div>
  {prodCards.map((card, index) => (
    <ProductCard
      key={index}
      expand={expandFormHandler.bind(this, card.pid)}
    />
  ))}

  <Route path={props.match.url + "/:id"} exact component={Modal} />
//<Route path="/form/:id" exact component={Modal} />   //Tried this too
</div>
  );
```

**Modal.js:**

```
<h1>{props.match.params.id}Hello</h1>
```

The modal is not rendering even it's `useEffect()` is not executed.

Now if I place Modals Route in Body.js like following the Modal is rendered but not in the same page below `ProductCard`

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/form" exact component={Forms}></Route>
    <Route path="/form/:id" exact component={Modal} />
    <Route path="/" exact component={ShopCards}></Route>
</Switch>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what is your goal? You want to show Modal component on the same page with Forms component if url contains :id?

Comment: if you want modal on the same page with the ProductCard. I don't think using route like that can achieve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

The `Route` rendering `Forms` is using an exact match, i.e. when the path is ***exactly*** "/form"

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/form" exact component={Forms}></Route> // <-- exact match!!
  <Route path="/" exact component={ShopCards}></Route>
</Switch>
```

When the path is any subroute, i.e. "/form/3" it is no longer an exact match and `Form` is no longer rendered.

## Solution

Remove the `exact` prop from the root route.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/form" component={Forms}></Route> // <-- general match
  <Route path="/" exact component={ShopCards}></Route>
</Switch>
```

Forms.js

```
return (
  <div>
    {prodCards.map((card, index) => (
      <ProductCard
        key={index}
        expand={expandFormHandler.bind(this, card.pid)}
      />
    ))}

    <Route path="/form/:id" component={Modal} /> // <-- more specific match
  </div>
);
```